# CodeIgniter - Access database credentials outside CI

Tags: codeigniter

I'm building an app using CodeIgniter and the CometChat software.

I need to connect CometChat to the same database as the CI is using.

I don't really want to have to enter database details all over the site, so I would like to pull the details from the CI database.php file.

I have tried to `require` the database.php file but it doesn't seem to work.

If anyone has a workaround I would love some help.

Comment: Before including or requiring the file, did you define your `BASEPATH` variable? [CodeIgniter protects itself](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/database.php#L1) against direct script access.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most codeigniter files have include protection on it as follows:

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

You must define basepath before including it, like so:

```
define('BASEPATH', 'dummy');

$db = array('default' => array());

require 'path/to/config/database.php';
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
echo $db['default']['hostname']; // this might echo 'localhost'
```

Of course, you'll have to see your `database.php` file to see how it's laid out.

Comment: Thanks for that ... im just wondering what would be in the 'dummy' part

Comment: Doesn't matter, that value is used for other parts of the CI engine not relevant to db access.  We just assign any value to satisfy the check.

Comment: Hmmm it doesnt seem to be working ... so in the cometchat file i put in the 3 lines you specified ... Do i have to add the if ( ! defined('BASEPATH'.... to the new file as well?

Comment: All im seeing is the Failed opening required 'core/application/config/database.php' ... But its pointing to the right location

Comment: Ok, so now i added ../ and its not throwing that error, but when i try and echo $db['default']['hostname'] .... its completely blank

Comment: Ok, i have fixed it now ... i am using different environments and i forgot to set it ... works perfect now .. thanks heaps!!

Comment: I am having same issue and approached same solution but still my $db is NULL when ia use "var_dump($db)". 
Note: I am using $db outside CI. Code is below:

abc.php
include('/var/www/data.xyz/application/config/database.php');
function test_db()
{
  global $db;
  var_dump($db);die;
}